# Kazam Screencaster: Region selection doesn't appear

Tags: gnome-panel, kazam

I have Ubuntu with gnome-panel.

In Kazam Screencaster When I click the **Record Region** everything button, dropdown goes into inactive mode and doesn't select region.

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug on launchpad - it is a configuration problem.

To fix, go to **Settings > Configuration Editor**

In configuration editor, browse to **Apps > Metacity > General**

If **compositing_manager** value is unchecked, check it.

[image]

Reopen Kazam Screencaster and Region Selection works.